# Which method is better and faster,with include or without in PHP

Tags: php

I included 2 files(header,footer) in one page

and normal page without include function (header and footer in one page)

Which methods are faster and which method is les load on server ?

Comment: You're asking if it's faster to already have the data in the file, or to include it? I really wouldn't be bothering yourself with concerns like this, to be honest.

Comment: Fastest is if you don't need to run any code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a total irrelevant tweaking of performance.

If you put everything into one file it may be 0.000000000001% faster, but you can't read the code anymore.

If you have many files (which is way better for organizing your code) use APC or something to accerlerate your code.

Answer (score 0):

Having everything in one page might be a bit faster but it would be by so little it wouldn't be noticeable. Having your static files(header,footer,navbar) on different files has another advantage. When you want to change something in your website, let's say your header, you only need to edit header.php and not every single page. I think that alone justifies that tiny delay.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you trying by yourself:

```
$start = microtime(true);
include "myfile.php";
var_dump(mictotime(true) - $start);
```

As you would see, you don't have to worry about this kind of matters.